# Can we rename the 'cqc' tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

While conducting a normal review on the Suggested Edits queue, I noticed a user had created a tag labeled "[cqc](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/cqc/info)". Confused, I checked the edit, and noticed that the edit was for the tag wiki entry, where it identified the tag as "Close Quarters Combat".

As I lack the power to edit the tag to something like "close-quarters-combat", should there be an effort made by a diamond moderator to change the name (if possible) of the tag to something meaningful, so I'm (hopefully) the last one confused by it?

Comment: The tag page doesn't show any questions (might be caching).  Can you link to the question you saw?  I agree we should fix this, and if it's a new tag you can just edit the tags on the post.

Comment: @MonicaCellio It seems like the tag was removed from the question it was created on between the asking of this question and the time you checked the tag page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you asked this question, Vincent [edited](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/revisions/45641/3) the question that introduced the [cqc](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cqc) tag, removing [cqc](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cqc) and replacing it with [combat](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combat), which is much more popular. At this point, then the tag is used on zero questions.

For what it's worth, I've renamed [cqc](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cqc) to [close-quarters-combat](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/close-quarters-combat) (technically, I [created the second one and merged the first into it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197731/274942)), although I doubt that it's going to be useful in the future. It might end up being a synonym of [combat](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combat), like [civil-war](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civil-war) eventually became a synonym of [warfare](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warfare). Apparently, [the tag will soon be destroyed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/274942), unless we synonymize it.

Comment: I think that close-quarter-combat may be too specific. Combat is not popular enough to have a sub-tag.

Comment: @Vincent Okay. Then we can just let the system automatically delete the tag.

Comment: Looks like [someone else has just used the tag again](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/45746/modern-near-future-melee-armor)

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh I removed it. The tag will hopefully die.